# check if a form checkbox exists with a specific value

Tags: jquery

I extract a json string from a form element. Then, I need make a decision based on if that certain form field exists and its value is xxx. I am failing to pass the form field name into the .length function below:

```
$('input[type="radio"]', myform).each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var jsonData = $.parseJSON($this.attr("data-dependsOn"));
        $.each(jsonData, function(index, element) {
             console.log("element.param : " + element.param + " & element.value : " + element.value );
            if ( $('#myform input[name=''' + element.param + ''']').length > 0 ) ) {
                console.log("indeed exists");   
            } else { 
                console.log("not so much");
            }   
        });
});
```

A sample console.log :

> element.param : homeType & element.value : condo

By the way, I cannot use the element's id or class attributes.

How do I pass `element.param` in to the `input[name='']` while escaping quotes appropriately?

thanks in advance.

Comment: use a combination of single/double quotes like line 1.  Something like `$("#myform input[name='" + element.param + "']")`

Comment: `if ( $('#myform input[name="' + element.param + '"]').length > 0 ) ) ` or

`if ( $('#myform input[name=\'' + element.param + '\']').length > 0 ) ) `

Comment: i am receiving an error pointing to $('#myform input[name="' + element.param + '"]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do any of the following.

```
if ( $('#myform input[name="' + element.param + '"]').length > 0 ) 
//_________________________^_____________________^___________
```

or using javascript quotes escape.

```
if ( $('#myform input[name=\'' + element.param + '\']').length > 0 ) 
//_________________________^_____________________^___________
```

> **Note:**
>   You also have an extra closing `)` in the if condition line.

Comment: For the love of JavaScript, don't ever escape quotes (single or double), if you have the option not to!

Comment: @Johan there is no reason not to.

Comment: Sure, Apart from making it over complicated for juniors and not so fun to read.

Comment: @Johan Yeah, you are right. :) It was not so much fun on the first days of 'javascript\'n'. :D

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, this works. I had an extra closing ) at the end.

Comment: @CFNinja actually I added that in the answer as a **note**